Insert horizontal line in the new Outlook
For various reasons, I often want to have a horizontal line in my emails, like this:

In "Old" Outlook, I could insert various types of horizontal lines using autocorrects such as "---", "***", and "===". However, these do not seem to work in "New" Outlook, and I do not see an option in the Insert tab.
How do I insert a horizontal line?
EDIT: Would the downvoter care to explain his or her reasoning? While I admit that I do not have much experience with SuperUser (I mostly frequent Worldbuilding and Law), I can't find any glaring issues with my question.

New outlook misses lots of features. If you miss one, there is no reason to stick to new outlook. Just revert back to old outlook.

In the "New" Outlook, the autocorrect shortcuts like "---", "***", and "===" for inserting horizontal lines are not available. However, you can still insert a horizontal line using the following steps:

Place your cursor where you want to insert the horizontal line.
Go to the Insert tab on the ribbon.
Select Shapes from the options.
From the Lines gallery, choose the type of line you want to draw.
Click and drag your mouse on the canvas to draw the line. To draw a perfectly horizontal line, press and hold the Shift key while you draw.

If you need to format the line, you can use the Shape Format tab to change the color, weight (thickness), and style of the line.
More information: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/draw-a-line-in-word-or-outlook-d74bd9de-ff43-4942-a75b-1843803d2293
Hope it helps!

Voted down. You correctly state that new outlook does not have this option, and then you present a solution that doesn't work in new outlook either. Was this answer AI generated? They too make these kind of rookie mistakes. Do note that AI generated answers are not allowed on SuperUser.

OmO, sorry for the misleading, because the article mentions the mail, I thought it would be possible to apply New Outlook message because it did work with Word, and it was my mistake to upload the answer without testing.

However, i have found a post in feedback collection website, and you could vote for it. As i know, many features of current products are designed and upgraded based on customers’ feedback. You can also make suggestions on that website and hope Microsoft will notice this in the future. https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/a1200900-44da-ee11-a73d-6045bdbdc092
